# Return Multiple li's as a "slide"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm putting together a quick little status board that shows active and upcoming github issues.

I have them all pulled in and formatted as a simple list and found a nice jQuery plugin that cycles through each item as a sort of slideshow. However, it was requested that it show multiple issues at once to fill up the screen more.

So on each slide swap it would display, say 5 LI items at once versus just 1. And then swap to show the next 5 and so on.

HTML

```
...
<ul id="issue-list">
  <li class="issue"></li>
    ...
  <li class="issue"></li>
</ul>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            $('#issue-list').swapmyli({
                swapTime: 900, // Speed of effect in animation
                transitionTime: 700, // Speed of Transition of ul (height transformation)
                time: 4000, // How long each slide will show
                timer: 1, // Show (1) /Hide (0) the timer. 
                css: 0 // Apply plugin css on the list elements.
            });
        });
</script>
```

JS

```
(function(e) {
    e.fn.swapmyli = function(t) {
        function s() {
            var e = i.parent().find(".timer span");

            e.animate({
                width: "100%"
            }, r);

            var n = i.find("li:first").outerHeight(true);
            i.find("li:first").fadeOut(120);

            i.animate({
                height: n
            }, t.transitionTime);

            i.find("li").hide();

            e.animate({
                width: "0%"
            }, 60);

            i.find("li:first").remove().appendTo(i).fadeIn(t.swapTime)
        }
        var n = {
            swapTime: 300,
            transitionTime: 900,
            time: 2e3,
            timer: 1,
            css: 1
        };

        var t = e.extend(n, t);
        var r = t.time - t.swapTime;
        var i = this;

        i.wrap('<div class="swapmyli clearfix"></div>');
        i.after('<div class="timer"><span></span></div><br class="clear" />');

        e(window).load(function() {
            var e = i.find("li:first").outerHeight(true);
            i.height(e);
            i.find("li").hide();
            s()
        });

        if (t.timer == 0) {
            i.parent().find(".timer").hide()
        }

        if (t.css == 0) {
            i.parent().addClass("nocss")
        }
        setInterval(s, t.time)
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: If that's the entire plugin (I'm assuming it is) there is not an option to show more than one item. Personally, I use [carouFredSel](caroufredsel.dev7studios.com) as it's quite extensive.

Comment: That is a very extensive plugin. I'll have to give it a go in the interest of saving time!

Comment: It is...If you use it, something like this will work for you: `$('#issue-list').caroufredsel({items: {visible:5}})`

Comment: I ended up using it. And it works great save for it's "responsive" features. But I was able to get things how I wanted with a little extra CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if outerHeight() will function correctly with [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), but you may try changing these lines:

```
var n = i.find("li:first").outerHeight(true);
i.find("li:first").fadeOut(120);
```

To the following:

```
var n = i.find("li").slice(0, 4).outerHeight(true);
i.find("li").slice(0, 4).fadeOut(120);
```

That's sort of a quick answer, but hopefully you're catching my drift. Probably need to play around with it a little bit :)

Comment: I get your drift. It didn't seem to have any affect though. Script still returns one item at a time. I'll keep trying.